# How to get handle of function output with sapply in R?

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, lapply, sapply

Let's suppose that this is my code:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123,kind="Mersenne-Twister",normal.kind="Inversion")
y = runif(20,0,50)

simulation <- function(y){
  x <- rnorm(length(y),3,0.125)
  lm(y ~ x)
}

fit <- lapply(1:10, function(dummy) simulation(y))


coef <- sapply(fit, coef) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

How can I collect the 10 simulated `x` variables generated from the function `simulation` in a data frame?

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in the `fit` object. A single one can be extracted with `fit[[1]]$model$x`. Programmatically we can get all of them in a data frame like this:

```
xs = lapply(fit, \(x) x$model$x)
data.frame(i = rep(seq_along(xs), lengths(xs)), x = unlist(xs))
#      i        x
# 1    1 3.153010
# 2    1 3.044977
# 3    1 3.050096
# 4    1 3.013835
# 5    1 2.930520
# 6    1 3.223364
# 7    1 3.062231
# ...
```

Or, if you want lots of info you can use `broom::augment` instead. This will return the full data, along with predicted values, residuals, etc.

```
result = bind_rows(lapply(fit, broom::augment), .id = "sim")
head(result)
# A tibble: 6 × 9
#   sim       y     x .fitted .resid   .hat .sigma .cooksd .std.resid
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 1     14.4   3.15    19.2  -4.78 0.141    15.1 0.0101      -0.350
# 2 1     39.4   3.04    24.6  14.8  0.0612   14.7 0.0353       1.04 
# 3 1     20.4   3.05    24.3  -3.89 0.0633   15.1 0.00252     -0.273
# 4 1     44.2   3.01    26.2  18.0  0.0525   14.5 0.0437       1.26 
# 5 1     47.0   2.93    30.4  16.7  0.0603   14.6 0.0438       1.17 
# 6 1      2.28  3.22    15.6 -13.3  0.234    14.7 0.164       -1.04
```

You might also like `bind_rows(lapply(fit, broom::tidy), .id = "sim")` which will give you one row per coefficient and `bind_rows(lapply(fit, broom::glance), .id = "sim")` which will give you one row per model.

Comment: With `xs = lapply(fit, \(x) x$model$x)` I get `Error: unexpected input in "xs = lapply(fit, \"`

Comment: Is there a way to have a `length(y)` x  `nSimul` matrix of the `x`s with column index equal to the number of simulations?

Comment: You  must have an older version of R, the `\(x)` syntax is new in R 4.1.0. You can replace it with `xs = lapply(fit, function(x) x$model$x)`.

Comment: If you want the simulations in columns not rows, use `bind_cols(xs)`

Comment: Ok and with `result = bind_cols(lapply(fit, broom::augment), .id = "sim")` I get a "messy" output. Is it possible to extrapolate only the `x`s from the regression and drop from the tibble other columns? i.e. Y, fitted values, ... Just plain `x` with col index equal to the number of simulation

Comment: I mean, that's what `bind_cols(xs)` is. `augment` is what you use when you want all the extra stuff---and it's meant to be in a tidy long format with `bind_rows`, `augment` won't play nicely with `bind_cols`.